# AngularJS Custom Directive - Match More Than One Field?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a custom directive obtained from https://github.com/neoziro/angular-match that matches two form fields. However, how can I customize it to match more than one field? Here is better explanation of what I mean:

```
-Form Field 1
-Form Field 2
-Form Field 3
-Form Field 4

-Confirmation (I want this one to match either Field 1,2,3 OR 4.)
```

Currently, I can only match it up to one field.

**HTML Form:**

```
<input type="text" 
       name="correctAnswer" 
       ng-model="quiz.quizData.correctAnswer" 
       match="answer1">
<div ng-show="theQuiz.correctAnswer.$error.match && !theQuiz.correctAnswer.$pristine">Answers do not match!</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('match', []).directive('match', ['$parse', matchDirective]);

function matchDirective($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(function () {
        return [scope.$eval(attrs.match), ctrl.$viewValue];
      }, function (values) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('match', values[0] === values[1]);
      }, true);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to write your own directive for this, especially since `angular-match` plugin is no longer maintained.

To watch multiple form inputs, just pass the `ng-model` of each desired input to the directive. Here I called it `match`.

```
<input type="text" name="firstNameOne" ng-model="firstNameOne"/>
<input type="text" name="firstNameTwo" ng-model="firstNameTwo"/>
<input type="text" name="firstNameThree" ng-model="firstNameThree"/>

<input type="text" name="confirmFirstName" ng-model="confirm" match="{{[firstNameOne, firstNameTwo, firstNameThree]}}"/>
```

Now for the directive

```
app.directive('match', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.doValidation = function(matches) {
            //Validation logic.
         }
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('confirm', function() {
              scope.matches = JSON.parse(attrs.match); //Parse the array.
              scope.doValidation(scope.matches); //Do your validation here.
          });
       }
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing validation of form inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/cpgoette/und9t5ee/

Comment: this worked! However, one thing I wanted to ask. I noticed that if you enter a matching entry, then go and change it in one of the inputs, it still says "match". Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can $observe the match attribute to watch for changes. Then just call the same validation function as before. Fiddle is updated: https://jsfiddle.net/cpgoette/und9t5ee/